# Ruby 1.9.3 add unsafe characters to URI.escape

Tags: ruby, escaping, sinatra, uri, ruby-1.9.3

I am using Sinatra and get parameters from the url using the `get '/foo/:bar' {}` method. Unfortunately, the value in `:bar` can contain nasty things like `/` which leads to an 404, since no route matches `/foo/:bar/baz`/. I use `URI.escape` to escape the URL paramter, but it considers `/` valid a valid character. As it is mentioned [here](http://usernameguy.livejournal.com/3495.html) this is because the default Regexp to check against does not differentiate between unsafe and reserved characters. I would like to change this and did this:

```
URI.escape("foo_<_>_&_3_#_/_+_%_bar", Regexp.union(URI::REGEXP::UNSAFE, '/'))
```

just to test it.

`URI::REGEXP::UNSAFE` is the default regexp to match against according to the [Ruby 1.9.3 Documentaton](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-escape):

```
escape(*arg)
Synopsis
    URI.escape(str [, unsafe])

Args
    str
        String to replaces in.
    unsafe
        Regexp that matches all symbols that must be replaced with
        codes. By default uses REGEXP::UNSAFE. When this argument is
        a String, it represents a character set.
Description
    Escapes the string, replacing all unsafe characters with codes.
```

Unfortunatelly I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant URI::REGEXP::UNSAFE
```

And as [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ripienaar/graphite-graph-dsl/issues/19) suggests, this Regexp was removed from Ruby with 1.9.3. Unfortunately, the `URI` modules documentation is generally kind of bad, but I really cannot figure this out. Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm a little confused. If a client needs to issue a request containing a reserved character as a literal character, then it should be sent percent-encoded. i.e `:bar` *must* be sent to your sinatra server containing `%2F` instead of `/`. There's nothing for your sinatra server to encode.

Comment: But the client sends the `:bar` from templates that are _rendered_ by the sinatra server, and that's where I escape the URLs. Also I redirect from `/?search=bar` to `/search/#{params[:bar]}` like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657074/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[URI#escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-escape) is not what you are looking for. You want [CGI#escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape):

```
require 'cgi'
CGI.escape("foo_<_>_&_3_#_/_+_%_bar")
# => "foo_%3C_%3E_%26_3_%23_%2F_%2B_%25_bar"
```

This will properly encode it to allow Sinatra to retrieve it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves my problem. Is the URI module somehow deprecated?

Comment: No, it's not deprecated, it just works a bit differently. It's for a different purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you would have better luck with `CGI.escape`?

```
>> require 'uri'; URI.escape("foo_<_>_&_3_#_/_+_%_bar")
=> "foo_%3C_%3E_&_3_%23_/_+_%25_bar"
>> require 'cgi'; CGI.escape("foo_<_>_&_3_#_/_+_%_bar")
=> "foo_%3C_%3E_%26_3_%23_%2F_%2B_%25_bar"
```